# Why new nonclustered index cause more IO reads on table?

Tags: sql-server, nonclustered-index, filtered-index

We are in process of creating new non-clustered index for specific views. One of the view looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[table_backup]
UNION ALL
(
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tableA] a
LEFT JOIN
[dbo].[tableB] b on
a.column1PK = b.column1PK and
a.column2PK = b.column2PK and
a.column3PK = b.column3PK and
a.column4PK = b.column4PK
WHERE
 a.column_5= 'D'
    AND a.column_6 <> ''
    AND a.column3PK = b.column3PK
    AND a.column_7 <> 'D'
    AND a.column_7 <> 'M'
)
```

I already prepared non-cluster filtered index for tableA:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_column_6_INCLUDE]
ON [sap].[BSEG]
(
    column_6 ASC,
)
INCLUDE
(
    column_5
    column_7  
)
WHERE column_6 <> ''
      AND 
       a.column_5 in ('D','K')
          AND column_7  <> 'D'
              AND column_7 <> 'M';
```

I add also value 'K' for column_5 because in filter because we have similar second view which contains same table but with filter on column_5 equals to 'K'.

Below are execution plans:

Without index:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJwAlxDAF

Sum of logical reads on all tables = 49 189
CPU time = 971 ms
Elapsed time = 489 ms

With index:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJzSB7dAF

Sum of logical reads on all tables = 127 932
CPU time = 2109 ms
Elapsed time = 1010 ms

Query which I run for test performance:

```
SELECT TOP (10000) * INTO #temp FROM [dbo].[view]
```

Do you know why adding index cause performance decrease ?

Comment: Why you want to select *, Please use selective columns and see. select * seems to return so many columns, Please check your cardinality estimate issue also.

Answer (score 3):

**Context**

Without knowing the full definition of both tables, here’s what I can see.

1. Your **faster** plan is doing a single clustered index scan of Object6 and returning 160k rows.
2. Your **slower** plan is doing a nonclustered index scan on Object6, reading 399k rows and only retuning 57k of them. Then it’s following that up with 24,570 key lookups.
3. Based on their name, I assume columns `column1PK` - `column4PK` are Primary Keys on `tableA`. As such, don't need to be part of any index you create.

**Things you can try**

1. Add `column_5` as the Key Column, instead of `column_6`. That is the only column that is compared differently in your query compared to the filtered index. So filter that column first.
2. Consider removing `SELECT *`, if possible, and select only the columns you need. `SELECT *` is a bad practice, and will almost always produce a Key Lookup.

Below would be a good index candidate.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_column_5_includes]
ON [sap].[BSEG]
(
    column_5 ASC
)
INCLUDE
(
    column_6,
    column_7
)
WHERE column_6 <> ''
    AND column_5 IN ('D','K')
    AND column_7 NOT IN ('D','M');
```

Additionally, make this changes to your query. For starters, `a.column3PK = b.column3PK` is in your `JOIN` and in your `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT [col1], [col2], [colN]
FROM [dbo].[table_backup]

UNION ALL

SELECT [col1], [col2], [colN]
FROM [dbo].[tableA] a
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tableB] b
    ON a.column1PK = b.column1PK
        AND a.column2PK = b.column2PK
        AND a.column3PK = b.column3PK
        AND a.column4PK = b.column4PK
WHERE a.column_5 = 'D'
    AND a.column_6 <> ''
    AND a.column_7 NOT IN ('D','M');
```